# How to Hide elements based on id in ng-repeate

Tags: angularjs

How to hide an element based on elements id, I tried to hide the element without using:

```
document.getElementById('lis'+divId).style.visibility = "hidden";
```

but this worked while using individual elements but in case if I use `ng-repeat` it does not hide the element.

```
 <li ng-repeat="dashBoardAddWidgetList in dashBoardAddWidgetLists"  
            ng-click="addTemplate(dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetType,$index)"
                     id="lis{{$index}}" >{{dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetName}}</li>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.addTemplate = function(name,divId) {
                  //$scope.templates.push( { name: 'achPayBankProcess.html', url: '/Templates/dashboard/widgets/achPayBankProcess.html' });
                  $scope.templates.push( { name: name, url: '/Templates/dashboard/widgets/'+name,isSelected:1});
                  document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility = "hidden";
                  $scope.listCount--;
              };
```

Comment: An example of what you're trying to do would be useful.

Comment: <li ng-repeat="dashBoardAddWidgetList in dashBoardAddWidgetLists"  ng-click="addTemplate(dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetType,$index)" id="lis{{$index}}" >{{dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetName}}</li>                                           i need to hide these elements in controller once i have selected the list element ,The element is hidden if ng-repeat is not used i.e for individual elements

Comment: use ng-hide instead..

Comment: Priyanka i need to hide the list element based on the condition Onclick

Comment: Please post your code, formatted, in your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: finally  ng-hide="isselect==$index"

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way like as what is @priyanka said .(take my answer like a key )

```
$scope.items = [{isshow:false,name:"Me"},{isshow:false,name:"We"},   
               {isshow:false,name:"I"},{isshow:false,name:"Us"}]
```

//html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div ng-hide="item.isshow">
{item.name}<button ng-click="ShowOrHide(this.item, $index)">show/hide</button>
</div> 
</div>


//click event
$scope.ShowOrHide(context,index)
{
context.ishsow=true;
$scope.items[index]=context;
}
```

Comment: ng-hide="isselect==$index" works  by setting the index value in controller  $scope.isselect=$index;

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-hide` instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="dashBoardAddWidgetList in dashBoardAddWidgetLists"  
    ng-click="addTemplate(dashBoardAddWidgetList)"
    id="lis{{$index}}"
    ng-hide="dashBoardAddWidgetList.hide">
    {{dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetName}}
</li>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.addTemplate = function(widgetList, divId) {
    var name = widgetList.widget.widgetType;

    $scope.templates.push({
        name: name, 
        url: '/Templates/dashboard/widgets/'+name,
        isSelected: 1
    });

    // Set flag for hide on true
    widgetList.hide = true;
    $scope.listCount--;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if instead of ng-hide..it will boost performance on ng-repeat because ng-hide will keep hidden element in DOM but ng-if will remove that element form DOM..so we cant modify it in browser inspect

Answer (score 0):

controller.js

```
$scope.addTemplate = function(name,divId) {

              //$scope.templates.push( { name: 'achPayBankProcess.html', url: '/Templates/dashboard/widgets/achPayBankProcess.html' });
              $scope.templates.push( { name: name, url: '/Templates/dashboard/widgets/'+name,isSelected:1});
              alert('lis'+divId);
              document.getElementById('lis'+divId).style.visibility"hidden";
              $scope.listCount--;
              $scope.isselect=divId;
              };
```

{{dashBoardAddWidgetList.widget.widgetName}}